# Suggestions for performance improvements Java code

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations

Hello I am just doing this for fun and I am trying to figure out if there is a more efficient/faster way to do this. Make all possible combinations of a given list of numbers and letters then print them to a text file. I currently have this and am looking for suggestions.

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class combos {

  public static void main(String[] args){

     char[] alphabet = new char[] {'0','1','2','3','4','a','b','c','d','e'};

     StringExcersise.possibleStrings(5, alphabet,"");
  }
  } class StringExcersise {
     public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr){

        if(curr.length() == maxLength) {
          try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("./Combos.txt", true))) {
          out.println(curr);
          }catch (IOException e) {
          System.err.println(e);}

        } else {
          for(int i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
              String oldCurr = curr;
              curr += alphabet[i];
              possibleStrings(maxLength,alphabet,curr);
              curr = oldCurr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It currently takes me about 26 seconds to run.

Comment: just a thought, but why not keep all the possible value in a static list and write it once in the file, instead of doing it each time for all possible values. I/O operations are costly.

Comment: That would be a possibility if it was for a different purpose. Every time I run it I will be using a different list of numbers and letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest performance bottleneck is IO. Every time you open/close a file it's very expensive.  I suggest you open it just one.  Additionally you don't need to create a collection first as this gets expensive as the collection grows, just write the results to the buffered file as you calculate them.

You can get a relatively minor improvement by building a `char[]` instead of a `String` and printing the char[].

```
class StringExercise {
    static void possibleStrings(char[] alphabet, PrintWriter pw, char[] curr, int index) {
        if (index == curr.length) {
            pw.println(curr);
            return;
        }
        for (char c : alphabet) {
            curr[index] = c;
            possibleStrings(alphabet, pw, curr, index + 1);
        }
    }
}

public class Combos {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("combos.txt")) {
            StringExercise.possibleStrings("01234abcde".toCharArray(), pw, new char[5], 0);
        }
        System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to run%n", (System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1e3);
    }
}
```

prints

```
Took 0.030 seconds to run
```

I checked it generates the output expected.

Answer (score 0):

Writing to file at the end and replacing recursion with tail recursion reduces time to less than 1 sec:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    char[] alphabet = new char[]{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};

    Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
    possibleStrings(5, alphabet, "", permutations);

    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("./Combos.txt", true)))
    {
        out.println(permutations);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public static void possibleStrings(int maxLength, char[] alphabet, String curr, Set<String> permutations)
{
    if (curr.length() == maxLength)
    {
        permutations.add(curr);
    }
    else
    {
        for (char anAlphabet : alphabet)
        {
            possibleStrings(maxLength, alphabet, curr + anAlphabet, permutations);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make each set of numbers and letters on a new line in the outputted file?

Comment: I guess you can append "\n" after each String value, when it would be written on file, they would be in new line.